# Android Videoview constantly showing black screen and no audio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

So as the title says, it's been two days and i tried every solution on stackoverflow and i'm officially stuck.

I'm sure the video extension and encoding is correct i used
The xml part is inside 2 linearlayouts which is inside a scrollview which is inside a constraintlayout, the view is a fragment

This is my XML :

```
                                <FrameLayout
                                    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="50dip" >
                                <VideoView
                                    android:id="@+id/video_view"
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="172dip"
                                    android:layout_gravity="top|center"         
                                    android:visibility="visible"/>
                                </FrameLayout>
```

This is the fragment code :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings_general, container, false);

        intro = (VideoView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.video_view);

        MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(getContext());
        intro.setMediaController(mediaController);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video);
        intro.setVideoURI(uri);
        intro.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                intro.setZOrderOnTop(true);
                intro.start();
            }
        });

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
```

In my manifest the internet premission is added :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Printing the URI shows the correct project name with a "/" and some numbers at the end.

Comment: make sure that the internet permission is written in the manifest file and your URI is perfectly correct.

Comment: @MuhammadAsad i already did that but i updated my post, thanks.

Comment: you cannot return a layout view in on create view method. you initialize the view in rootview but it cannot be returning this is the error.

Comment: @MuhammadAsad can you please elaborate ? i didn't understand exactly what you mean, you can do it in an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this method instead of your code

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle 
savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings_general, 
container, false);

    intro = (VideoView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.video_view);

    MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(getContext());
    intro.setMediaController(mediaController);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video);
    intro.setVideoURI(uri);
    intro.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            intro.setZOrderOnTop(true);
            intro.start();
        }
    });

    return rootView ;
}
```

Comment: i update my answer your code is perfect but you need to return your layout view instead call super method.

Comment: only add this line at the end of the method :

return rootView ;